# mysql update table and select another table

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have been considering creating a stored procedure to update a single row on table A and then select another row from table B. Table B's results would be then used. However, i am not very familiar with stored procedures and i would rather use native sql to complete the task. I am curious if it is possible to accomplish an update and then a select with native sql and how would i do so? as well as is it possible to create a temporary(on the fly) sql procedure using php instead of actually storing the procedure in the database?

thanks

Comment: By issuing separate update and then select statements you can achieve what you want without stored procedures. You can issue these statements from php or any other programming language that can connect to MySQL.

Comment: Right i totally understand i can do that i was hoping there is a way to do with making one call?

Comment: There is no way to execute a select and an update in one statement. But you can execute multiple statements in a single call to the MySQL database, see for example http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php However, such calls pose an additional risk for sql injection attacks, so you really need to think through when and how you use such calls.

Comment: im using pdo and using specific placeholders, so i think this shouldnt be an issue?

Comment: Mysql does not support multiple statements within a prepared statement. In PDO you can turn on the emulated prepared statements option, in which case PDO's prepare does support multiple statements. But it is not the same as mysql's prepared statement. Definitely less secure, but probably secure enough.